# Change Font Color on Overflow

Tags: css, text, fonts, colors, overflow

This is where I am trying to accomplish this effect:
http://www.smalldot.agency/ccren/goals-page/

As the "val" bar increases in width, it should overlap the "current" text ((which is the same text as "val" but a different color)). I am able to force "current"'s copy on top of the "val" element, but I can't get it to rest underneath instead.

If I place the "current" p class below the "val" div class, the the text from "current" shows up south of the progress bar, rather than beneath it.

Also, the z-index: 0; doesn't seem to be doing anything to fix the problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="progdiv" style="width:100%;">
    <p class="current">1,234</p>
    <div class="val" style="width:3%;">1234</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.val {
  height:100%;
  border-radius:3px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: #019BA9!important;
  text-align: left!important;
  vertical-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #bbbbbb;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.progdiv {
  background-color: #FFFFFF!important;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 2px #bbbbbb!important;
  text-align: left!important;
  overflow: hidden!important;
}

.current {
  text-indent: 6px;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: left!important;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: #019BA9!important;
  position:absolute!important;
  text-align: left!important;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: I figured it out. I gave "current" z-index: 0; and I gave "val" z-index:1; along with position:relative; (z-index doesn't work on elements that aren't given a position). It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position: absolute;` to the `.val` CSS. Also remove the `height:100%` from both the `.val` and `.current` CSS.